# Multiple Quotas for Single Sales User

Tags: forecast, quota

In real business scenario, a Sales Rep can be working on multiple opportunities of different types. Business needs to set multiple Quotas for single Sales User either depending on the Opportunity Type or Sales User region or any other differentiating factor.

Current forecasts capability does not support setting of multiple Quotas for single Sales user. There are Ideas for the same but not many votes.

Is there any alternative to achieve this with minimum to no customization, or is there any AppExchange product which provides this capability.